# Create a threadpool by ThreadPoolTaskExecutor or ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, executorservice

I'd like to create an executor service that I can use as follows:

```
@Asyn(value = "asyncService")
public void task() {
    //...
}
```

When should the `@Bean` be created using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` or `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean`?

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService getAsyncService() {
    //when to favor ThreadPoolTaskExecutor over ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean
}
```

Are there any cases where one should be favored over the other?

Comment: Javadoc for these two classes seems informative enough..http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean.html

Comment: Still it doesn't tell me which one to favor when using it with `@Async`.

Answer (score 0):

Favor direct injection of the `TaskExecutor` unless running under an app server, mainframe, or other environment where you need special handling of threads.  Like the docs say, it's easy to get confused on which class you're using otherwise.